# Firebase functions with firestore using something like cache

Tags: node.js, firebase, function, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I have some datas in firestore, like this.

[My datas in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7acT.jpg)

And I have a GET function, let user can get a json object.

```
return
{
"Android_APPID": "xxxx",
"Andorid_BannerID": "ccc",
....
}
```

Can I use something like cache to make function just return this json string, not always load from database?

Comment: This is very interesting problem. I think you can implement it on backend. Question is how this "cache" should know when to read from database, when return cached data? 2nd question, I cannot imagine the scenario you will use it. Can you provide use case?

Answer (score 0):

However your question is incomplete or misleading, what I think you can do is **cache this value in the frontend** itself: like in app or website.
If you want to do this cache on backend, you can't do it with cloud functions. You need to create your own backend and apis to communicate with firestore and use NGINX to cache.

For more details, you need to elaborate your question a bit.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I want to cache it in the backend, it doesn't seem to work.